# Как соблюсти DRY при пошаговой обработке данных?

Tags: python, exception-handler, dry

Обрабатываю я данные от разных людей, которые которые отправляют мне файлы мне в csv формате. Пакеты данных конечно бывают с ошибками, неполные и т.д. Вот висит у меня на сервере мой скрипт, который периодически читает мою почту, извлекает файлы  их обрабатывает как надо.
Понятно, что для того, чтобы при всяких косяках программа не падала, я поставил ***try ... except*** в каждой функции или методе класса и возвращаю признак - хорошо закончилась обработка в подпрограмме или нет. Каждая функция-метод имеет такую структуру:

```
def files_reading(self):
    """Read the files."""
    self.response["exit_is_ok"] = False

    try:   # do something here
       ...
       self.response["file"] = some_file
       self.response["exit_is_ok"] = True
    except Exception as error:
       self.response["exit_message"] = f'{error} while reading'

    return self.response
```

То есть при входе я признак ставлю на False, и меняю на True, когда не было исключений. Если в функции были проблемы, ясное дело надо пропустить этот пакет данных. То есть в основном цикле при каждом вызове метода стоит проверка "Ok" или не  "Ok".
Тогда основная программа выглядит так:

```
def main():
    """Calculate Amazon reports."""
   ...

   for sender in senders:
        ...
        izi_report = globals()[task_name](path_to_files_folder)
        # ===data reading===
        readed = izi_report.files_reading()
        pd_files = readed["files"]
        if not readed["exit_is_ok"]:
            print(received["folder"], "--->", readed["exit_message"])
            continue 

        # ===data_processing===
        data_response = izi_report.data_processing(**pd_files)
        if not data_response["exit_is_ok"]:
            print(received["folder"], "--->", data_response["exit_message"])
            continue

        #  ===write to xlsx===
        files = data_response["files"]
        xl_response = izi_report.excel_writer(files)
        if not xl_response["exit_is_ok"]:
            print(received["folder"], "--->", xl_response["exit_message"])
            continue
        ...
```

Видно, что постоянно повторяется одна и та же последовательность строк. Позже вместо принта будет отправка письма.
Так вот вопрос. Как в этом случае соблюсти правило **DRY**. Ведь  "continue" в функцию не засунешь.   Или более общий вопрос. Есть какой то прием чтобы красивее реализовать эту идею.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заворачивайте исключение в каждой функции в специфическое (чтоб было сообщение об ошибке в зависимости от функции), а в главной функции обрабатывайте исключение один раз:

```
def files_reading(self):
    """Read the files."""
    try:   # do something here
       ...
       self.response["file"] = some_file
    except Exception as error:
       raise Exception(f'Error while reading: {error}') from error

    return self.response


def main():
    """Calculate Amazon reports."""
   ...

   for sender in senders:
      try:
        ...
        izi_report = globals()[task_name](path_to_files_folder)
        # ===data reading===
        readed = izi_report.files_reading()
        pd_files = readed["files"]

        # ===data_processing===
        data_response = izi_report.data_processing(**pd_files)

        #  ===write to xlsx===
        files = data_response["files"]
        xl_response = izi_report.excel_writer(files)
        ...    
     except Exception as error:
       print(received["folder"], "--->", f'Error: {error}')
```